# Update invoking class with Webclient events

Tags: c#

I have a WPF application with a viewmodel (mainviewmodel) containing a method DownloadFile().

Removing some in this case non-interesting codes it looks like this:

```
class MainViewModel() {
      private async void DownloadFile(Object obj)
            {
                var file = (SharepointFile)obj;
                ISharepointServer server;
                if (file.isSharepoint365())
                {
                    server = new Sharepoint365();
                }
                else
                {
                    server = new Sharepoint2013();
                }
                file = server.DownloadFileFromServer(file);
        }
}
```

And my DownloadFileFromServer(file) looks like this:

```
class Sharepoint2013 {
    public SharepointFile DownloadFileFromServer(SharepointFile sharepointfile) {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                Uri uri = new Uri(file.remoteUrl);
                // Download file
                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, filename);

                // Save parameters
                file.localname = filename;
                file.localmajorversion = file.majorversion;
                file.localminorversion = file.minorversion;
                file.updatesavailable = false;
                return file;
      }
}
```

My question is how to update the gui using the events from the webclient (DownloadProgressChanged and DownloadFileCompleted).
It has to be the mainviewmodel (the invoking class) that updates the UI.

Should I create events in the **callee** class that propagates the Webclient events to the **calling** class?
Or is there a way to propagate the original events from the **webclient** to the calling class?

Please note that the Sharepoint2013 and Sharepoint365 names of the classes are not relevant for the question, they are named during dev. for me to remember what is what.

Comment: Can't you use httpClient with async / await support?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this, but maybe callbacks could work for you? I'd much rather use HttpClient, but if you must...

```
class Sharepoint2013 {
    public SharepointFile DownloadFileFromServer(SharepointFile sharepointfile, Action<file> onCompleted) {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += () =>
        {
            // Do your "Save" stuff here and then call the callback.
            // Save parameters
            file.localname = filename;
            file.localmajorversion = file.majorversion;
            file.localminorversion = file.minorversion;
            file.updatesavailable = false;

            //return file;
            onCompleted?.Invoke(file);
        }

        Uri uri = new Uri(file.remoteUrl);
        // Download file
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll check it out in the office on Monday and accept it as answer once I tested.